# Challenges in Information security management

Tags: governance

> Information security management involves challenges that are
>   essentially unique due to the combination of technical and
>   organizational constraints. Identify two such challenges and discuss
>   in depth how these can affect the way information security management
>   is performed within an organization.

I have an essay to write on the above. Can anyone spare some ideas on how I can tackle this? In the terms of technical and organizational constraints?

I think technical limitation refers to things that you have to do that are system based, but that you are unable to achieve due to some reason?

Organisation should be like, for example, your CEO requesting for information that he has no access to and demands that he has access granted?

Please enlighten me if I'm wrong.

Comment: We don't do your homework around here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework

Comment: I understand that Lucas, not asking for help to write on my behalf. I just need some idea on what does it mean by technical and organizational constraints? Like maybe an example so i have an idea.

Comment: @LucasKauffman Homework questions are perfectly ok here *if the OP shows that they understand the question and provides their attempt to answer it.*

Comment: @jonovan This question is too undefined. Can you refine it and provide your own thoughts?

Comment: Agree. @Jonovan, if you could break out some ideas you've already had we might be able to provide input in terms of our experience.

Comment: From my point of view, i think technical limitation refers to the something that you have to do that is system base but unable to achieve due to some reason? Organisation should be like, for example, your CEO request for information that he has no access to and demands that he has access granted? 

Please enlighten me if i'm wrong.
Many thanks for all that have replied

Comment: I just need a correct example of the 2 above to get me started. I don't wish to be writing on something when i got the concept wrong. Anyone who can provide me with an example of the above would be great so i know if i am on the right track.

Comment: I have edited your comment into the question. I think the question is now specific enough to keep it open.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the main problem is that most of the technical solutions reduce the comfort or efficiency of the users. So you have a strong organisational support from the top-level managment. You can only reach good acceptance of information security if all users understand the importance of information security.